# How many new lines before namespace declaration in PSR?

Tags: php, psr-2, psr-12

PSR has a fairly clear stance regarding new lines after namespace declaration:

> When present, there MUST be one blank line after the namespace declaration.

But what about blank lines before namespaces? Are there any rules or limitations about it? I believe I've seen something somewhere, but cannot find now.

Comment: The answer is 6. Just 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The section *3. Declare Statements, Namespace, and Import Statements* in [PSR-12](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) talks about the various parts of the start of the script and states

> The header of a PHP file may consist of a number of different blocks.
>   If present, **each of the blocks below MUST be separated by a single**
>   **blank line**, and MUST NOT contain a blank line. Each block MUST be in
>   the order listed below, although blocks that are not relevant may be
>   omitted.

(emphasis mine).

Also following is the example

```
<?php

/**
 * This file contains an example of coding styles.
 */

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Vendor\Package;

use Vendor\Package\{ClassA as A, ClassB, ClassC as C};
```

which shows the spacing.

The main thing I read from this is not about defining the number of blank lines before but more defining that any of the components must have a single blank line between them.

Just a comment about [PSR-2](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/), is does state

> **Deprecated** - As of 2019-08-10 PSR-2 has been marked as deprecated.
>   PSR-12 is now recommended as an alternative.